# Can't create index in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I want to create an index using this query:

```
CREATE  INDEX `PRIMARY` ON `elements` (`id`) USING BTREE
```

Or something like that, I've tried several queries:

```
1. CREATE  INDEX `PRIMARY` ON `elements` (`id`) USING BTREE
2. CREATE  INDEX 'PRIMARY' ON `elements` (`id`) USING BTREE
3. CREATE  INDEX `PRIMARY` ON 'elements' (`id`) USING BTREE
4. CREATE  INDEX PRIMARY ON elements (`id`) USING BTREE
5. CREATE  INDEX PRIMARY ON elements (id) USING BTREE
```

I've also tried the 5 queries above without "USING BTREE". But I'm always getting this message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PRIMARY ON 'elements' (`id`) USING BTREE' at line 1
```

This one works:

```
CREATE INDEX test ON elements (brandid);
```

I can't really discover a big difference between the two.
Why can't I create an index with name PRIMARY?

Comment: PRIMARY its a [Reserved Word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: But I can create an index with that name when I use phpmyadmin, why is phpmyadmin able to use that word?
Also, when I put in in quotes "", than it's a string, than it's not reserved anymore I think?

Comment: You can only use the name `PRIMARY` when creating a primary key.

Comment: @TiiJ7 Reserved words are permitted as identifiers if you quote them as described in Section 9.2, [Shema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/create-index.html):  Thats dint aply to PRIMARY ??

Comment: @Melon From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html): `The name of a PRIMARY KEY is always PRIMARY, which thus cannot be used as the name for any other kind of index.`

Comment: Guess I'll have to go for @Zagor23's answer than. I was hoping for some other solution.
Thanks for the quick responses.

Comment: @TiiJ7 it make sense. so the only solution its to change the name of the index he whant to create

Comment: Don't call your index `PRIMARY`.  Call it, for example, `elements_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhpMyAdmin creates `PRIMARY KEY` (which is actually unique index) using syntax like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `elements` ADD PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

You can have only one PRIMARY KEY per table.

Comment: thats to create primary key, he ask abaut index.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for another solution, but I'll have to go for this one since it's the only one that works.

Comment: @Melon I know what he is asking, but I have tried to create simple, one-column index called PRIMARY on table that already have PRIMARY KEY and I get error `#1068 - Multiple primary key defined `, which means that phpMyAdmin actually tries to create PRIMARY Key when instructed to create index named PRIMARY.

Comment: @Melon No problem, I hope it gets better :)